# Showing an entire function f(z) is monomial

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Given f is entire and satisfying $|f(z)| \leq 3|z|^{\alpha}$, show that $f(z) = cz^{\alpha}$ for some constant $c$ if $\alpha$ is a positive integer, and $f(z) = 0$ if $\alpha$ is not an integer.

I already showed that $f(z) = a_1z + a_2z^2 + ... + a_nz^n$, where $n$ is the largest positive integer less than $\alpha$. I tried to consider the function $g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^{\alpha}}$, which has modules less than or equal to $3$, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Thank you.

EDIT: I should write the title "monomial", not "monic".

Comment: 'Monic' means that the leading coefficient is 1.  I think you mean 'monomial'.

Comment: You're very much on the right track. For $\alpha$ an integer, $\frac{f(z)}{z^\alpha}$ gets you to the target. Generally, look at $$\frac{f(z)}{z^{\lfloor \alpha\rfloor}}.$$ If $\alpha$ is not an integer, what can you say about that function?

Comment: @Hayden You're right. I should write "monomial" instead of "monic". Thank you.

Comment: @DanielFischer I looked at $g(z)$ as you said, and $g(z) = \frac{a_1}{z^{\alpha-1}} + \frac{a_2}{z^{\alpha-2}} + ... + a_{\alpha}$, but I couldn't grab my head around it. I know $|g(z)| \leq 3$. What should I go from here?

Comment: How does the function behave near $0$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ahhh, I see it now. The function blows up near 0 and cannot satisfy the inequality. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f has a power series expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$. Using Cauchy's inequalities, (which are simple consequences of Cauchy's integral formula) we have
$$
\forall\,r>0,\quad |a_n|r^n\leq M(r)
$$
where $M(r)=\sup\{|f(re^{i\theta})|:\theta\in\Bbb{R}\}$. By assumption we have $M(r)\leq 3r^\alpha$, thus
$$
\forall\,r>0,\quad |a_n| \leq 3 r^{\alpha-n}
$$

- If $n>\alpha$, by letting $r\to\infty$, we obtain $a_n=0$.
- If $n<\alpha$, by letting $r\to0$, we obtain $a_n=0$.
  So, if $\alpha\notin\Bbb{N}$, there are no $a_n$'s left, and $f\equiv0$. on the other hand if $\alpha$ in an integer we conclude from the above discussion that
  $f(z)=a_\alpha z^\alpha$, with $|a_\alpha|\leq 3$.

Comment: I'm new to the site. I tried to click on the upper arrow next to your answer, but it requires me to have at least 15 reputations. How can I accept the answer? Thanks again!

Comment: it is the check sign under the lower arrow.